# Cypress whitelist only our domains

Tags: cypress

I have a page, that has ads in it, sometimes, in an iframe, sometimes not.

Problem is that the page times out (60s), even if it looks loaded. I think it might be ads or some other tracking, therefore I would like to add whitelist to our resources URL so that any ads or similar resources get dropped.

This might not be 100% accurate way to test, but good enough for our case.

I have tried using this in beforeEach (not optimal, but if it would work I would make it into a command and work with it)

```
cy.server({
    whitelist(xhr) {
        //  Basicly, does it match any of whitelisted URLs?
        console.log('whitelisting', xhr.url)
        const url = new URL(xhr.url);
        const URLwhitelist: string[] = Cypress.env('URLwhitelist');
        if (!URLwhitelist.length) {
            return true
        }
        return URLwhitelist.some(allowerdUrl => {
            if (allowerdUrl.split('.').length == 2) {
                return url.host.includes(allowerdUrl);
            } else if (allowerdUrl.startsWith('*.')) {
                allowerdUrl = allowerdUrl.slice(1);
                return url.host.includes(allowerdUrl);
            }

            throw new Error(`Unparsable whitelist URL (${allowerdUrl})`);
        });
    }
});
```

I have also found some blacklist option in `cypress.json`, but I need whitelist rather than blacklist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress has a default whitelist and information can be found here:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Options

> Change the default whitelisting
>
> cy.server() comes with a whitelist function that by default filters
>   out any requests that are for static assets like .html, .js, .jsx, and
>   .css.
>
> Any request that passes the whitelist will be ignored - it will not be
>   logged nor will it be stubbed in any way (even if it matches a
>   specific cy.route()).
>
> The idea is that we never want to interfere with static assets that
>   are fetched via Ajax.
>
> The default whitelist function in Cypress is:

```
const whitelist = (xhr) => {
// this function receives the xhr object in question and
// will whitelist if it's a GET that appears to be a static resource
return xhr.method === 'GET' && /\.(jsx?|html|css)(\?.*)?$/.test(xhr.url)
}
```

> You can override this function with your own specific logic:

```
cy.server({
whitelist: (xhr) => {
// specify your own function that should return
// truthy if you want this xhr to be ignored,
// not logged, and not stubbed.
}
})
```

It appears you can override permanently that whitelist by setting options on cypress.server:  https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cypress-server.html#Syntax

Comment: Didn't know about override for all test, thanks. Yet my problem sourced mainly from `fetch`.